# MySQL connection with C# through PHPMyAdmin created database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

We are sitting with a problem regarding MySQL database insertion.
We have installed .NET connector and added MySql.Data.dll, MySql.Web.dll, MySql.Entity.dll to the /bin. As displayed in the code below, we are also using the right namespace. 
However, when we try and insert data through the website, nothing gets inserted.
The details for the database connection is provided from the webhotel.
Domain location: http://testing.cce-solutions.dk/testBooking/is/interested/

C# code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection;
    string server = "db.cce-solutions.dk";
    string database = "web626445";
    string uid = "******";
    string password = "******";
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into  web626445 (yourName,YourEmail,YourPhone,Category,Description) values(@Name,@Email,@Telephone,@Category,@Description)", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", YourName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", YourEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", YourPhone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Category.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayMessage.Text = "Error occured. Please try again later.";
    }
    connection.Close();
    }}
```

**EDIT:** 
***Firstly, thanks for all the answers!*** So we have implemented Rahul and ActiveHigh's answers and updated the code. Furthermore, we have added a way to check if the connection is a success or not. Now when we try to insert data we get the error message. The test location is still the same.
Here is an image of the table in the database: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2c70ty9qb1h7bw/ScreenshotDatabase.png
Anyone have any idea what is going wrong or an idea how to debug it?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection;
    string server = "db.cce-solutions.dk";
    string database = "web626445";
    string uid = "******";
    string password = "******";
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";


    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            DisplayMessage.Text = "Data entered succesfully.";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into  Booking (yourName,YourEmail,YourPhone,Category,Date,Description) values(@Name,@Email,@Telephone,@Category,@Date,@Description)", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", YourName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", YourEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", YourPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Category.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "test");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayMessage.Text = "Database connection failed.";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayMessage.Text = "Error occured. Please try again later.";
    }

    connection.Close();
```

Comment: Remove the line `connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;` inside `try` block. You are reassigning the connection string.

Comment: How can be so sure that data not getting inserted? are you getting any exception? did you checked in DB whether new data is present? Is connection getting established properly?

Comment: Have updated the code, but no data is inserted still. We check that the table is empty through phpMyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using database name inside insert statement-

```
...

string server = "db.cce-solutions.dk";
    string database = "web626445";
    string uid = "******";
...

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into  web626445 (yourName,YourEmail,YourPhone,Category,Description) values(@Name,@Email,@Telephone,@Category,@Description)", connection);
```

I see that `web626445` is the `database` not `table`. Use table name instead. Since you have wrapped it up with a try block you cannot see the error.

And check that you have the table correctly created.