# MySQL connection to phpMyAdmin created database with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

As our question got closed yesterday, we unfortunately have to open a new one. So here goes.
This is the old question: [MySQL connection with C# through PHPMyAdmin created database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120497/mysql-connection-with-c-sharp-through-phpmyadmin-created-database)

**Firstly, thanks for all the answers!** So we have implemented Rahul and ActiveHigh's answers and updated the code. Furthermore, we have added a way to check if the connection is a success or not. Now when we try to insert data we get the error message from the catch. The test location is still the same. Here is an image of the table in the database: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2c70ty9qb1h7bw/ScreenshotDatabase.png

Anyone have any idea what is going wrong or an idea how to debug it?
(We have checked inside phpmyadmin whether or not the table is empty with a SQL query. It is empty.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection;
string server = "db.cce-solutions.dk";
string database = "web626445";
string uid = "******";
string password = "******";
string connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";


connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    connection.Open();
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        DisplayMessage.Text = "Data entered succesfully.";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into  Booking (yourName,YourEmail,YourPhone,Category,Date,Description) values(@Name,@Email,@Telephone,@Category,@Date,@Description)", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", YourName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", YourEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", YourPhone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Category.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "test");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayMessage.Text = "Database connection failed.";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DisplayMessage.Text = "Error occured. Please try again later.";
}

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use `DisplayMessage.Text = "Error occured. Please try again later."` instead of `DisplayMessage.Text = ex.Message;` which would show you **exactly** what failed? This has nothing to do with either PHPMyAdmin nor with MySQL itself, it's just a case of you being able to get a meaningful error description. The error is pretty much obvious also - look at your screenshot, then look at your query. Deduce what doesn't match.

Comment: Yeah, we were finding these things out at the same time you posted this answer. Thanks none the less!

Answer (score 0):

We found out we had assigned erroneous column names. In the insert statement we wrote yourName, yourEmail and so on (as you can see below) which needed to be changed to Name, Email, and so on.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into  Booking (yourName,YourEmail,YourPhone,Category,Date,Description) values(@Name,@Email,@Telephone,@Category,@Date,@Description)", connection);
```

Furthermore we removed the if loop since we did not need it and added a throw to the catch to get more detailed feedback. Hope this can help anyone stuck in the same problem.

***Don't be us - check your column names! ;)***